# OnExpanded event for any item in a treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview

I'd like to get an event for any expansion of a treeviewitem in my treeview.

The reason for this, a bit unrelated to the original question:
I am creating a tree that relates closely to an xml file tree, but I am allowing an include element  in the xml so the tree can go across multiple files. I'd like to set the itemssource property of treeviewitems within my treeview upon expansion.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the `TreeViewItem.Expanded` event as an attached event :

```
<TreeView TreeViewItem.Expanded="TreeViewItem_Expanded"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    ...
</TreeView/>
```

In code-behind, you can identify the `TreeViewItem` that initiated the event using the `OriginalSource` property :

```
    private void TreeViewItem_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem tvi = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
        if (tvi != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("TreeNode '{0}' was expanded", tvi.Header));
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you mean the visual descendants, you can get them through the ItemsContainerGenerator of the TreeViewItem

Comment: This was so helpful, thank you, I wish had a bounty to give you. Final summary: The visual descendents I wanted were not created yet during the expanded event. In the expansion event I saved the OriginalSource, then in an arbitrary converter method for a binding, I got the visual descendent with ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) and updated the ItemsSource.