# How can I set an event handler for all TreeViewItems in code?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I want to subscribe to the TreeViewItem.Expanded event on TreeView level. In xaml, this is easy: [OnExpanded event for any item in a treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387981/onexpanded-event-for-any-item-in-a-treeview)

However, I subclassed TreeView and therefore do not have a xaml file. What can I do in C# code to achieve the same?

Comment: You still can insert your object in XAML.

Comment: @dymanoid: But how would I do that and still be able to offer the user of my class a TreeView and not a UserControl (where I would have to create dependency properties for ItemsSource, etc.)

Comment: `AddHandler(TreeViewItem.ExpandedEvent, (RoutedEventHandler)TreeViewItem_Expanded);`?

Comment: Okay, if you're creating a custom control without XAML, then you have to do that in code.

Comment: @ASh: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! If you make your comment an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In WPF can I attach the same click handler to multiple buttons at once like I can in Javascript/Jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780132/in-wpf-can-i-attach-the-same-click-handler-to-multiple-buttons-at-once-like-i-ca)

Comment: @chw, i would rather close it as a dupe. I think I found a good dupe target (about Buttons but logic is the same)

Comment: @ASh Well, the accepted answer contains the solution to this question, but the question is very different imo. Since I could not find the question you linked even though I looked for several hours, I think this question might be helpful to others.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
TreeView.AddHandler(TreeViewItem.ExpandedEvent, (RoutedEventHandler)TreeViewItem_Expanded);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just walk recursive through the node and add your Eventhandler

```
void AddHandler(Node node) {

  foreach(varnode in node.Nodes) {
  node.OnExpanded += nodeExpandedEvent;
  if(node.Nodes.Count > 0) {

     this.AddHandler(node, nodeChecked);
    }
   }
 }
```

Or use the solution Ash provided