# TreeViewItem expanded event

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello I am working with a `WPF` application where I am wanting to have an event fire before I expand an item on a `TreeView`. I know that there isn't an event already for this but I am not sure how to add one the way that I am doing this so any help will be appreciated.

here is the xaml.

```
 <TreeView x:Name="TreeView" Margin="20">
        <TreeView.Resources>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                   <!-- Some style -->
              </Style>
              <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:DirectoryPathItem}">
                   <!-- some template -->
              </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
 </TreeView>
```

I am loading in code behind.

```
    private void LoadBaseDirectories()
    {
        var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");

        var directories = directoryInfo.GetDirectories();

        foreach (var directory in directories)
        {
            TreeView.Items.Add(new DirectoryPathItem()
            {
                Children = new ObservableCollection<PathItem>(),
                Path = directory.FullName,
                Header = directory.Name
            });
        }
    }
```

Is there a way that I can call an event before expanding the `TreeViewItem` so I can load the children?

Comment: Is this the method you are looking after https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387981/onexpanded-event-for-any-item-in-a-treeview

Comment: well thank you, but that isn't exactly what i want. so this fires after it is expanded.

Comment: How would you expand an item with no children? Or what do you mean by "load the children"?

Comment: @mm8, that is a good question. I cant, I had to use the option that KOTIX provided. I load the underlining children but when I expand that child i load its children. It seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading the children items before you actually expand may result in an unresponsive UI where the user does not understand why the list is empty.

I would suggest adding an item which represent the background task (i.g.: a loading spinner of some sort) and add proper items as soon as they are discovered.

Once done you may remove the loading spinner item.

This way, you won't need a new event and the user will understand what is going on.